# Are actors taught to roll their "r"'s?

Tags: pronunciation

A particularly prominent example of a rolled *r* user is the actor Jeremy Brett, who played "Sherlock Holmes" in the 1980s Granada adaptations. I've noticed that several other actors, especially from the older generation, also use the rolled *r*. Is this something that actors are or were taught to do at drama school? If so, why?

Comment: Where? Are you American/English/Scottish/…? (BTW, Jeremy Brett apparently overcame a speech impediment and overcompensated by rolling r's, according to random internet sources.)

Comment: Yes...but any voice training would depend on nationality/ dialect.

Comment: @Kinopiko: It doesn't matter where *you* are, but it matters where the actors you're talking about are, and what you consider "prominent". There's not enough context to answer the question ("what are actors taught and why") without it. Presumably if you were in Scotland you wouldn't find rolled r's uncommon.

Comment: Which "rolled r?" In this case, we would benefit from a standard phonetic orthography.

Comment: An interesting question, but ultimately about acting, not English usage.  Voting to close.

Comment: Classic advice from Mrs. General in [_Little Dorrit_](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ha8-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=play+character+prunes&source=bl&ots=MI7OkOM1SP&sig=tHqBV5z_eSwVSwcffTgbxtqYe5E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV1L6o9IHRAhVU-GMKHQzfBtIQ6AEIRDAJ#v=onepage&q=play%20character%20prunes&f=false): "'Papa' gives a pretty form to the lips. 'Papa,' 'potatoes.' 'poultry,' 'prunes and prisms.' You will find it serviceable  if you say to yourself on entering a room 'Papa, potatoes, poultry, prunes and prisms.'" Or you can specialize in _r_ rolling by sayng "prunes and prisms" over and over.

Answer (score 4):

Many actors are taught to [enunciate clearly](http://www.ehow.com/about_4586256_vocal-exercises.html), perhaps to ensure their lines are heard above a snuffling coughing audience, or to counter unpredictable acoustics in some theatres.

I'm sure that some actors who had trained for the stage would have then applied stage techniques to the screen, where close mics and sound stages would have made those old tricks unnecessary.
It's possible that the rolling "r" would be one of those tricks.

Comment: <insert *Singin' in the Rain* reference here>

Answer (score 3):

It really depends where the actors are from. Some drama schools would teach it, others would not. But a great many people in England roll their r's since birth, and I am not sure about Warwick, but it is possible that Jeremy knew how to roll his r's a long time ago.

As for me, I can easily roll an 'r' as can most of my Kiwi friends. So, no need to learn it in drama school.

Answer (score 1):

The rolled or trilled R in question is a form of classical English pronunciation.

Before Queen Elizabeth II modernised her pronunciation, the trilled R was quite commonly spoken. In Britain, even to this day, dramas schools teach the trilled R as part of their voice exercises, and some choirs will not admit someone if they cannot rolled their Rs. Mr Brett's trilled R was very much in keeping with the character and period of SH.

Comment: Do you have any references which backup your claim, re Elizabethan pronunciation? A link would be great, thank you.

Comment: The modernised pronunciation I refer to is that of our present queen, not the 16th century monarch. Actors who have had classical training will have learned the trilled R. Some of us English still speak with the trilled R, but it is considered old fashion.

Comment: My bad, I mistaken Elizabeth II for Elizabeth I, coincides with Shakespeare and the rise of theatrical plays. It would be good to learn what years are considered to be "classical training", I'm btw totally ignorant in this field.

Comment: Classical training in Britain encompasses anything from Greek tragedies to Shakespeare and realist / expressionist in the 19th and early 20th centuries.